# "A non well formed numeric value encountered in" with while loop

Tags: php

I'm setting up a while function that adds four every time it runs. But I get this weird error.

> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in.

I would like to fix this issue only I couldn't find any info regarding this problem in the instance of a while loop. Thank you in advance.

```
$x= 2012;

while($x <= 2084){
    echo "Schrikkeljaar:" . $x+=4 ."<br>";
}
```

Comment: `$x+=4;` and then `echo "Schrikkeljaar:" . $x ."<br>";` the problem here is that your are changing the value of `$x` in an addition in a echo statement

Comment: With `echo` always use `,`, it reduces the headaches a lot: E.g.: `echo "Schrikkeljaar:", $x+=4, "<br>";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap it in parenthesis:

```
echo "Schrikkeljaar:" . ($x += 4) . "<br>";
```

---

```
$x= 2012;

while($x <= 2084){
  echo "Schrikkeljaar:" . ($x += 4) . "<br>";
}
```

**Live Example**

[Repl](https://repl.it/repls/MaroonDistortedLocks)

Answer (score 2):

Php is trying to add "4<br>" to x. The easiest way to solve this is by adding that before:

```
$x= 2012;


while($x <= 2084){
    $x+=4;
    echo "Schrikkeljaar:$x<br>";
  }
```